# Issue with Segmentation Faults using Double Pointers in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

So my goal is to create an array of specific words. Here is the current code that I am using:

```
char **specificWords; //Global
specificWords = malloc(100 * sizeof( char *));

int addToArray(char * word, int i){
     specificWords[i] = word;
     printf("%s\n", specificWords[i]);
return 0;
}
```

Now just pretend in the main the function is repeatedly calling the function with incrementing "i" values and new "words". The print statement inside of the function works perfectly fine, but if I attempt to use the same print statement outside of the function, the program closes with a seg fault error.

Im still new to C programming but I have tried many different things, from allocating space for the array every time it is called. To different methods of incrementing such as "(**specificWords)++", and just using a loop in the main, but I really cannot figure it out.

Let me know if you need anything clarified, thanks.

EDIT: Here is the Main... I was trying to post a program to explain my issue, so here is the real one:

```
char **specificWords; //Global
char *globalString;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    specificWords = malloc(100 * sizeof( char *));
    int newLineCount = countLines(globalString);
    addToArray(newLineCount);
    printf("%s\n", specificWords[0]); //segFaults
    return 0;
}


int addToArray(int newLineCount){
   int ch;
   int loc = 0;
   char *tempKeyword;
   char temp[5026];
   int j = 0;
   int k = 1;
   j = 0;
   for(int i = 0; i < newLineCount; i++){
       while(1){
           //I read in a file and made the whole thing one big string which is global string
           ch = globalString[loc];
           if(ch == '\n')
               break;
           temp[j] = ch;
           loc++;
           j++;
       }
       loc++;
       temp[j] = '\0';
       tempKeyword = temp;
       specificWords[k] = tempKeyword;
       printf("%s\n", specificWords[k]);
       //k++; // if used seg faults...
    }
}
```

Comment: shre your main code. code of print in the main. or share the whole code

Comment: @MOHAMED, Okay give me a moment to post it.

Comment: @MOHAMED I updated it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have used a local string variable `char temp[5026];` defined inside of a function that will cease to exist after you exit the function, hence your printf will perfectly work in the function but will crash if you try to print anything outside of the `addToArray`.

   Explanation:

   ```
   {   // this is a block of code, for example function body

       char word[128]; // this string will exist at this level of code

       // it will work perfectly at this level

   }
   // now, there's no word variable at all, any pointer to it's address (data)
   // is invalid and could crash or you would read garbage from it
   ```
2. At this line:

   ```
   tempKeyword = temp;
   specificWords[k] = tempKeyword;
   ```

   You are always assigning whole temp buffer for each word, so you would get always the first word read in all specificWords indexes for example in `specificWords[2]`.
   To follow unwind's advice, rewrite the code to read every word to temp, from the beginning and then using strdup to copy the word into dynamically allocated memory that will survive returning from your function. Inside of your for loop:

   ```
    j = 0; // always reset the position to buffer from beginning
    while(1){
          //I read in a file and made the whole thing one big string which is global string
          ch = globalString[loc];
          if(ch == '\n')
              break;
          temp[j] = ch;
          loc++;
          j++;
      }
      loc++;
      temp[j] = '\0';
      tempKeyword = strdup(temp);
      specificWords[k] = tempKeyword;
      printf("%s\n", specificWords[k]);
   ```
3. You are counting your word indexes from 1 at this line:

   ```
   int k = 1;
   ```

   In C language, indexes in arrays start from zero, so you are losing one word from capacity of `specificWords` so you can store maximum of 99 words in the array. To solve this you could start with index `k=0`.

Comment: Oh okay I get it, so its pointing to memory, but it is memory that I constantly rewrite. Wouldn't that be the purpose of using a global variable though? So I could save whatever I wanted then just rewrite it? Or is it because I am using pointers that I cannot do that?

I took the others commentators advice of using strdup and it did not help.

Sorry if I'm being naive, but my teacher told me to use a global variable to store all the words. I don't really see how to do it if I can't copy words into the array without worrying about whether or not the words will turn into garbage or not :(

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out that it starts with 1!!! I have been working non-stop on this program and that solved everything, also I just ended up putting the function in the main, and then using "strdup" and it works perfect. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The pointer `word` that you are storing is probably going out of scope or becoming invalid in some other way.

It's often wrong to directly store pointers like you do, perhaps the `addToArray()` function should store the return value of `strdup(word)` instead. Then you also need to test it for failure, of course, since it allocates memory.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I implemented this and it worked perfectly (with a couple other changes). But seriously thank you!